# Recursive Query from end point Id to all its parents should be selected

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

ModuleUserPermission is my main table to query from where i get module ids for a particular user and in module table there i get menu ids to query menu table here is issue that module table consist of only end point menu ids and i want all of its parents as well

```
select * 
            from [ModuleUserPermission] mup 
             inner join Module ml on ml.Id = mup.Module_Id          
            --inner join Menu m on m.Id = ml.Menu_Id and m.IsActive = 1 
            where (NULLIF(@AspNetUsers_Id,'') IS NULL OR mup.AspNetUsers_Id = @AspNetUsers_Id)
```

[image]

SOLUTION:
this is what I did could we do it in proper way ?

```
DECLARE @TblTemp TABLE(
    Id int,
    ParentId int,
    Name nvarchar(max),
    Url nvarchar(max) NULL,
    SortOrder int,
    IconClass nvarchar(max) NULL,
    IsActive bit
);



;With temp as   (  
            select distinct m.* 
                from [ModuleUserPermission] mup 
                inner join Module ml on ml.Id = mup.Module_Id           
                inner join Menu m on m.Id = ml.Menu_Id and m.IsActive = 1 
            where (NULLIF(@AspNetUsers_Id,'') IS NULL OR mup.AspNetUsers_Id = @AspNetUsers_Id)

        union all

        select  m.* 
            from Menu m      
            inner join temp r on r.ParentId = m.Id
        where m.IsActive = 1 
     )
     INSERT INTO @TblTemp  select * from temp

;With relation (Id, IconClass,SortOrder, ParentId, Name,Url,IsActive, [Level], [OrderSequence])  
    as  
    (  
        select  distinct   m.Id, m.IconClass,m.SortOrder, m.ParentId, m.Name,ISNULL(m.Url,'') Url,m.IsActive, 1, cast(m.Id as varchar(20))  
        from @TblTemp m where m.ParentId = 0  

         union all  

        select p.Id, p.IconClass,p.SortOrder, p.ParentId,p.Name,p.Url,p.IsActive, r.[Level]+1, cast(r.orderSequence + '_' + cast(p.Id as varchar) as varchar(20))  
        from @TblTemp p 
        inner join relation r on p.ParentId = r.Id  

     )
select * from relation order by OrderSequence
```

Comment: Could you please provide tables structure and sample data as well as your desired output?

Comment: @StefanoZanini I have updated the post please see

Comment: Please post your structure and sample data as properly formatted text, because if you post images, this question won't be properly indexed. This, plus the fact that the link to the image may break, makes this quesiton and its answers less useful to users that may have the same issue in the future.

Comment: @StefanoZanini I have updated with solution please review it thats what I want .. could we do it in more proper way ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the relationship between top level menu items and lower level items is described in the `ParentId` column, you need to join your `Menu` table with itself, like this:

```
select  coalesce(m2.Id, m1.Id), coalesce(m2.Name, m1.Name)
from    [ModuleUserPermission] mup 
join    Module ml on ml.Id = mup.Module_Id          
join    Menu m on m.Id = ml.Menu_Id and m.IsActive = 1
left join Menu m2 on m.Id = m2.ParentId and m2.IsActive = 1
where   (NULLIF(@AspNetUsers_Id,'') IS NULL OR mup.AspNetUsers_Id = @AspNetUsers_Id)
```

The `left join` is because top level items won't join with any other item, so with a `inner join` you would lose them. This way you preserve them but with `null`s, hence the `coalesce`s